# `unnest_wider` multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a `tibble` with multiple columns with multiple `list` columns I'd like to `unnest_wider`.

```
df1 <- tibble(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values1 = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6),
  values2 = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)
```

I have tried many approaches that have not worked including adding a vector into `col`

```
df1 %>% # unnest_wider doesn't take multiple inputs
  unnest_wider(col = c(values, values2),
               names_sep = c("_1", "_2"), 
               names_repair = "unique")
```

and trying `mutate_at`

```
df1 %>% # mutate_at doesn't send data
  mutate_at(vars(values, values2), 
            ~unnest_wider(col = .,
               names_sep = c("_1", "_2"), 
               names_repair = "unique"))
```

How can I unnest multiple columns wider?

Comment: also see: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/740

Comment: what do you mean by that exactly? do you mean the expected outcome I would like?

Comment: I added more rows to the example -- this solution doesn't preserve column names

Comment: it would be the the original column name with `_1` and `_2` appended to each of the columns respectively, so `values` would becomes `values_1` and `values_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer I used

```
df1 %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(q_name = rep(c("1", "2"), nrow(.)/2)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = gr, 
              names_from = q_name, 
              values_from = values1:values2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(names(df1[-1]), ~ 
        df1 %>% 
             select(.x) %>%
             unnest_wider(c(!!.x), names_sep=c("_1", "_2"), 
                names_repair = 'unique')) %>%
  bind_cols(df1 %>% 
  select(gr), .)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  gr    values1_1 values1_2 values2_1 values2_2
#* <chr>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 a             1         2         1         2
#2 b             3         4         3         4
#3 c             5         6         5         6
```