# Unnest multiple columns from json

Tags: r, tidyr, jsonlite

I am wondering if there is a simpler solution to unnesting some JSON into a dataframe. I have the following JSON from an API:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

json <- '{   
  "result": {
    "id": "id_1",     
    "description": "description",     
    "var1": {       
        "var1Id": "a",       
        "var1Title": "aTitle"     
    },     
    "var2": {       
        "var1Id": "b",       
        "var2Title": "bTitle"     
    },     
    "var3": {       
        "var3Id": "c",       
        "var3Info": "c123",       
        "var3Type": "cType"     
    },     
    "var4": {       
        "var4Lvl2": [         
          {           
              "var4Id": "d",           
              "var4Title": "dTitle"         
            },         
          {  
              "var4Id": "d2", 
              "var4Title": "d2Title"         
          }       
        ]     
    }   
  }
}'
```

Next I usually turn it into a tibble and then begin using `tidyr::unnest_wider` for each list column:

```
## Note I use bind_rows to simulate how my actual data looks

json2 <- json %>%
    fromJSON() %>%
    tibble() %>%
    bind_rows(fromJSON(json) %>% tibble()) 


json2 %>%
    unnest_wider(".") %>%
    unnest_wider("var1", names_sep = "_") %>%
    unnest_wider("var2", names_sep = "_") %>%
    unnest_wider("var3", names_sep = "_") %>%
    unnest_wider("var4", names_sep = "_") %>%
    unnest_wider("var4_var4Lvl2") %>%
    unnest_wider("var4Id", names_sep = "_") %>%
    unnest_wider("var4Title", names_sep = "_")
```

The process above works just fine, but I feel like there is a simpler way to unnest all of these columns without having to enter in individual column names. Note that the number of columns and column names may change depending on the specific API query, so a solution that can handle those variations would be great.

Comment: I am not example to reproduce your example. `json2` is a tibble with one variable `.` and two records. The unnest commands give error `Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist. x Column 'var1' doesn't exist.` I am using recent versions of tidyverse packages and jsonlite.

Comment: Sorry - missed a line copying it from my script. It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found [akrun's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820415/unnest-wider-multiple-columns). I made a function to unnest all that can be used sequentially for each layer of nested list columns.

```
## create unnest_all function
unnest_all <- function(data){
  list_cols <- names(select(data, where(is.list)))
  data_non_list <- data %>%
    select(!where(is.list)) 
  
  if(length(list_cols) != 0){  
    map_dfc(list_cols, ~
              data %>%
              select(.x) %>%
              unnest_wider(c(!!.x), names_sep= "_", names_repair = 'unique')) %>%
      bind_cols(data_non_list, .) 
  } else {
    data %>%
      janitor::clean_names() 
  }
}

## use on json data
json %>%
  fromJSON() %>%
  tibble() %>%
  bind_rows(fromJSON(json) %>% tibble()) %>%
  unnest_wider(".") %>%
  unnest_all() %>%
  unnest_all() %>%
  unnest_all()
```